# Split string terms

Tags: ruby

I have the following string:

```
str = "peep toe t-shirt blue"
```

I need to split the items using space:

```
str.split(" ")
```

And I get

```
[pee, toe, t-shirt, blue]
```

The questions is that peep toe must not be splitted, because it's a name that makes sense together.
Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: Why does it more sense for `'peep'` and `'toe'` to be together than, say, `'toe'` and `'t-shirt'`? Your line `[pee, toe, t-shirt, blue]` should be `["peep", "toe", "t-shirt", "blue"]`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good to use split and then fix up the data later:

```rb
str = "peep toe t-shirt blue"
words = str.split(" ")
phrases = []
i = 0
while i < words.size
  if words[i] == 'peep' && words[i + 1] == 'toe'
    phrases << 'peep toe'
    i += 2
  else
    phrases << words[i]
    i += 1
  end
end
p phrases
```